# Does MongoDB have a way to update a document without dropping existing elements not contained in the update data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been using MongoDB with both .NET core and Node.js.  This question is specific to a node project I am working on, but I think the client language is irrelevant to my questions.

I have a document that has elements like name and address current ("add_current") below:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5d858718c1d9f856881dc9ce"),
   ...
   "name": "John Doe",
   "add_current" : 
   {
      "add1" : "456 Old Ave.",
      "city" : "Stafford",
      "state" : "VA",
      "zip" : "23234"
   },
   ...
}
```

Sometimes I am just updating some parts of the child object like this:

```
const updateDocument2 = function (db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    collection.update(
        { 
            '_id': ObjectID("5d858718c1d9f856881dc9ce") 
        },
        {
            $set: {
                name: "John Doe Jr.",
                add_current: {
                    add1: "123 New Street",
                }

            }
        }, function (err, result) {
            console.log("Updated the document");
            callback(result);
        });
}
```

When I execute the `$set` above, I delete the fields city, state and zip.  I don't want to do that.

I am seeking the most efficient way to update name and add_current.add1 without deleting other fields (like add_current.state). I realize that there are ways to do this with multiple touches to the data record (`.findOne(...)` then `.update(...)`).  Is there a way to do it with a single `.update(...)` touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are setting add_current's value to `{add1: "123 New Street"}`

try `{$set:{"add_current.add1": "123 New Street"}}`

Comment: Thank you, the "add_current.add1" makes it all work.