# How to update the childs value of an object present in the mongod using mongoose with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to update particular child's value which is actually present inside the object and wants all my rest value be the same.
i want to use mongoose npm package.

for example:

```
basic:{
 name: "ABC",
 mobile: 1234567890,
 age: 20
},
other:{
 pincode: 123456,
 email: "abc@abc.com"
}
```

**My Code**

```
 Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "basic.mobile": 1234567890 },
     {
           basic:{ name: "CDE"}
     },
     (err, doc) => {
       if (err) return res.send({ error: err });
       res.send(`updated`);
     }
 );
```

it works but it **override** the previous basic data and create a new one which i provided. it should update but also rest value should be there.
how can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB have a way to update a document without dropping existing elements not contained in the update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081435/does-mongodb-have-a-way-to-update-a-document-without-dropping-existing-elements)

Comment: i want to do this by using mongoose

Comment: It's the same thing replace update part with {"basic.name":"CDE"} instead of replacing basic's value with { name: "CDE"}

Comment: what if i want to update more then one value? how can make it dynaminc

Comment: add more keys in update objects like  {"basic.name":"CDE","basic.age":12}

Comment: thats the thing only, i don't want to hard code these fields.

Comment: you create a object say let updatedField={} and enter the fields based on your requirements as updatedField['basic.name']="CDE";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains the answer.  For Filter you are referring a single field using dot operator properly  that is

```
"basic.mobile": 1234567890
```

You should do similar thing for update as well, that is the second argument of your function call, the way you have defined is wrong becuase it is a new object - that should be used when you want replace whole `basic` object in DB.  If you want to just update the `name` field then you should use dot operator like below.

```
"basic.name":"CDE"
```

So the whole function would look like below.

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
     { "basic.mobile": 1234567890 },
     { "basic.name": "CDE"},
     (err, doc) => {
       if (err) return res.send({ error: err });
       res.send(`updated`);
     }
 );
```

Comment: thanks Lucia, but what if i want to add more updates in my object later. i dont want to hard code all the fields.

Comment: If you want to keep some fields as it is and update only few then this is the only way you can do it.  Or if you want to follow the way you have done in your question then just include all the fields, the one you want to update with the corresponding new value and all other fields with the old value.

Comment: I have created a dynamic object which will return me an update fields object as:->

let updateFileds = {};
  updateFileds = lead;

  Object.keys(req.body).map(type => {
    Object.keys(req.body[type]).map(child => {
      updateFileds[type][child] = req.body[type][child];
    });
  });